# Is it possible to use a calculated name of Azure API Management global property?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I need to retrieve the value of a global property. The name of the property comes from a request.
I would like to replace string 'ContosoHeader' in `{{ContosoHeader}}` with the parameter value from an incoming request. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at this moment, no. Only if number of such properties is limited you could use 'set-variable' to fetch them statically and then 'choose' to decide what value to use.

Alternatively you could try to store multiple values in single variable, storing JSON for example. This way you'll need to fetch only single known property.

Comment: I have 'chooses' and would like to get rid of them. Another solution is to make a request to Cosmos DB, but I do not like that.